# Simple Select query is taking more than expected time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm encountering slow performance when executing a simple `SELECT` query (`SELECT * FROM SampleData`) on a SQL Server database hosted on my local machine.

The table contains around 1 million records. Despite the relatively straightforward query, it takes approximately 20 seconds to retrieve the results. However, the result set seems to be lazily loaded (the rows are dynamically added right after I click the execute button).

What could be causing this, and what steps can I take to improve it?

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    DataType VARCHAR(115) NOT NULL,
    DisplayName NVARCHAR(515) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(MAX),
    StartDate BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Status BIGINT DEFAULT 1,
    CreationTime BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what the query is.  Look at the query plan, probably missing an index or your simple query is more complex than you think.

Comment: Is it possible that the DB engine is trying to pull all million rows, and the lazy loading is only happening on the side of the UI?

Comment: Show us your exact query, and post an actual execution plan to the [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) site for us to be able to inspect

Comment: Description VARCHAR(MAX) might contain a lot of data, so i think 1 mil rows is not too shabby. The way to improve it is not to fetch million rows and all columns just for fun

Comment: if you will remove temporary description from select statement is it return data faster? any indexes implemented? what is the most where conditions fields?

Comment: If you use SSMS, you can enter your query there and press Ctrl + L, then SSMS checks whether some performance improvements are possible. Often, it proposes some indexes which might help.

Comment: "the rows are dynamically added right after I click the execute button" when else do you want the rows to be loaded? Next week? 1m rows at say 1Kb each is 1Gb of data, that's going to take time.

Comment: If you want a truer picture of how long it takes then don't use SSMS, try something in C#, PowerShell or Python. In SSMS > Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid there's a "Non XML Data" option that limits how much SSMS downloads for things like your `Description varchar(max)` column with a typical setting around 65,535 bytes.